# Parent contains style rule

Tags: azure-devops

When trying to make a custom style for a rule with "Parent" on a PBI/Story DevOps tells me the `criteria is not valid`. No matter what I enter in the Value textbox.

What am I not getting ?

[image]

Comment: Neither = nor Contains work :/

Comment: "No matter what I enter in the Value" - such as? Please include actual examples.

Comment: @underscore_d could the string value of "Screening clearance" or "test123"

Comment: because there is no field "Parent", it's part of links and isn't field name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce this problem on my side, only the parent field cannot add styling rule.

Boards -> Settings -> Styles -> Rule criteria

[image]

So I will help you to report this issue on our [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1169228/cannot-set-styling-rule-for-parent-field.html) forum, and after confirmation by our engineer, this issue will be reported to the product team.  The product team would provide the updates if they view it.

Comment: More than one year later, the bug is still there. Not sure the Developer Community forum was that efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put in a Value. The value is the ID of the parent. Works fine.